# SQLite: autoincrement primary key questions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SQLite query:

```
CREATE TABLE Logs ( Id integer IDENTITY (1, 1) not null CONSTRAINT PKLogId PRIMARY KEY, ...
```

1. `IDENTITY (1, 1)` -> What does this mean?
2. `PKLogId` what is this? This doesn't seem to be defined anywhere
3. I want `Id` to be `integer primary key` with `autoincrement`. I would like to be able to insert into this `Logs` table omitting `Id` column in my query. I want `Id` to be automatically added and incremented. Is this possible? How can I do this?

At the moment when I try to insert without `Id` I get:

```
Error while executing query: Logs.Id may not be NULL
```

Comment: It looks like SQL Server syntax.

Comment: Yes, this `Create Table` query was converted from SQL Server to SQLite

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're actually using SQLite according to the syntax of your example.

If you are, you may be interested in [SQLite FAQ #1: How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1):

> Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will
>   autoincrement.

Comment: My issue was that I had used INT instead of INTEGER. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 12):

Change it to:

```
CREATE TABLE Logs ( Id integer PRIMARY KEY,....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are, you may be interested in SQLite FAQ #1: How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field?:

Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will auto increment.

This in fact is not entirely accurate. An integer primary key will indeed increment, however if the table drops all rows, it starts from the beginning again, It is important if you want to have all associated records tied correctly to use the autoincrement description after the primary key declaration on the integer field.