# How to auto increment in sqlite database iOS objective c

Tags: ios

[Table creation in sqlite manager]i am working on iOS objective c.In my project am using the sqlite manager for database purpose.I declared id is auto increment on the time of table creation of sqlite manager but whenever i execute my code on that time id is not autoincremted.
So decided to wrote the code for auto increment.
I wrote the code for id auto increment but it is not working properly.

Can any please suggest me which code is better for autoincrment.[this is the my database table creation in sqlite manager[Code for id auto increment][Table creation in sqlite manager][code for id creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1bs3.jpg)

[Code for table creation in sqlite manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQk8Z.jpg)

Comment: add some code here..

Comment: open your sqlite db in firefox and double check if that field is auto incremented

Comment: By the way, I would discourage the use of `stringWithFormat` to insert values in your database. You should use `?` placeholders (without any quotes) and then use the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions to bind values to those placeholders. If this is too much work, consider a library like [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which does this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the field as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, but when you insert data, do *not* include this field in the values being inserted. Don't try to increment this yourself. Let the database do this for you. If, after inserting the record, you want to know what the value assigned was, then call [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).

Comment: no currently if I am supplying primary key value then it  is showing me sql syntax error

Comment: @Chandni-Systematix - I'd suggest posting our own question, because if you supply a value, it should still work. I think we'd need to see the SQL, the error code and the [`sqlite3_errmsg()`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html). But trying to diagnose it here in comments isn't practical. Just ask your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to declare the `id` as Primary Key. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8519985/3288182)

Comment: i declared id as   _id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT but not auto incremented.Please see my screenshots also

Comment: can you try declaring your `_id` without the keyword **AUTOINCREMENT**? (`_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`).

And please post your **complete** code for declaring / creating your table

Comment: i already sent  screenshots with my question.Please check once.In my question code for id creation and table table creation in blue color that one please click on that image is displaying so check once.

Comment: so declaring it by `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` didn't work? Are you inserting numbers into it?

Comment: that didn't work.number was inserted but not auto incremented.

Comment: You said it wasn't working yet you accepted my answer? which is which?

Comment: whenever i declared id as _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY on that time i only insert the number

Comment: try implying that the `_id` is **NOT NULL** like this: **_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT**

Comment: Can please send me id auto increment code for objective c

Comment: I've already commented part of your query when you create your `_id` column (**_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT**). You've created your own table now right? the only problem is your `_id` primary key isn't increasing automatically. Please try and search on how to implement this in objective-c if you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

1. create table query

   ```
   CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
      ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
      NAME           TEXT      NOT NULL,
      AGE            INT       NOT NULL,
      ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
      SALARY         REAL
   );
   ```
2. query to insert

   ```
   INSERT INTO COMPANY (NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES ( 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 );
   INSERT INTO COMPANY (NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) VALUES ('Allen', 25, 'Texas', 15000.00 );
   ```
3. result

   ```
   ID          NAME        AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY
   ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
   1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
   2           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
   ```

Comment: note that no increment value where given in insert  query column id value will increased based on auto increment