# SQLite id auto-increment

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

I have created a SQLite table by using query below

```
 db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE__WORK + " ( " + ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT, Title TEXT, Time TEXT, Date TEXT)");
```

The ID now can be auto-incremented. But after I perform delete query, delete the first row data and add again, the ID will start from `1` instead of `2`.  Is it possible to make the id become `2` ?

Comment: you should add AUTOINCREMENT in primary key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite: autoincrement primary key questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519936/sqlite-autoincrement-primary-key-questions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite AUTOINCREMENT is a keyword used for auto incrementing a value of a field in the table.You do not need `ID1`.

See reference [here](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Please use this:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE__WORK + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,Name TEXT, Title TEXT, Time TEXT, Date TEXT)");
```

Comment: Thanks,but I don't understand why my ID will auto-incrementing although I didn't add  AUTOINCREMENT ?

Comment: Maybe if you tell me what is `ID1` in your code , I will try to give you an explanation

Comment: `public static final String ID1="ID";`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: If you look at documentation says: `purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.`

Comment: So, If the table is initially empty, then `ID` will be 1. When you delete the row ,table remain empty and `ID` become again 1.

Answer (score 3):

Make it `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`.

Here's what the [SQLite Autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) document say:

> If the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword appears after `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`,
>   that changes the automatic `ROWID` assignment algorithm to prevent the
>   reuse of `ROWIDs` over the lifetime of the database. In other words,
>   the purpose of `AUTOINCREMENT` is to prevent the reuse of `ROWIDs`
>   from previously deleted rows.